# how to use an Object injected with @Inject within a server endpoints @OnOpen method

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi

I have a Bean, which creates an instance of an object, which i need to inject into other beans. Everything works fine, i can print a property of the injected object in the @PostConstruct method, but if i try to call a method from that injected object inside the @OnOpen method of a ServerEndpoint it gives me a NullPointerException.

Here is my ServerEndpoint

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/websocket")
public class BeanThree {
    private String message = "test";
    @Inject private User user;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() { System.out.println(user.getUserName()); } <-- displayed in the console correctly
    public String getMessage() { return this.message; }

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        System.out.println("onOpen");
        System.out.println(user.getUserName()); <-- causes NullPointerException
    }
}
```

Is it possible to fix this?

Edit1:
Im using cdi 1.2, jetty 9.1, jsf 2.2, java-ee7 and websockets from java-ee7

Comment: Which websocket implementation are you using? atmosphere? Which framework? which server? glassfish? jetty?

Comment: My explanation is that the bean created by cdi is different from the bean created by the websocket container, since websockets are created only when a connection has been requested. Try probably to change the bean from applicationscoped to sessionscoped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that BeanThree is declared both a CDI bean and an endpoint at the same time.
It has to be split into two different beans:

```
@ServerEndpoint("/endpoint")
public class BeanThree {
    @Inject
    ApplicationScopedBean bean;

    @OnOpen
    public String onOpen(Session s) { System.out.println(bean); }
    @OnMessage
    public String onMessage(String message) { System.out.println(bean); }
}
@ApplicationScoped
public class ApplicationScopedBean { ... }
```

But there's another issue.
CDI / Websocket integration is very limited: out of the box you can inject `@ApplicationScoped` and probably `@Dependent` beans only.
From your snippet it seems you intend to use `@SessionScoped` User bean withing a Websocket session. That's not going to work because Websocket and HTTP sessions differ.
You'll have to manage Websocket sessions and session-bound data by yourself. Here's an [example](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/maven-websocketapi.html).

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to allow CDI to instantiate it as a CDI bean.

Then subclasses the following classes: `ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator`

```
@ServerEndpoint(..., configurator=MyCustomConfigurator.class)
@SessionScoped
@Named("myMessageHandler")
public class MyMessageHandler{

 @Inject
 private MyInjectable instance;

 ...
}

public class MyCustomConfigurator extends ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator{
  public <T extends Object> getEndpointInstance(Class<T> endpointClass) throws InstantiationException{
  //do cdi lookup for endpoint using the simple name.
}
```

To have a reference to the cdi BeanManager, have a look at this thread:
http://dominikdorn.com/2010/04/cdi-weld-manual-bean-lookup/

In your case, you dont have a reference to FacesContext, so use the ServletContext

Comment: can you elaborate on how to do a cdi lookup?

Comment: See the link on the updated question on how to get the reference to the beanmanager

Comment: In CDI 1.1/1.2, it's easier to do a manual lookup - `CDI.current().select(Class beanClass, Annotation...annotations).get()`